# Please don't use odd horizontal lines to drive LCD for both odd and even fields simultaneously?

Tags: lcd, datasheet, timing

Here's a datasheet for a small TFT LCD panel. http://www.yc-dz.com/productimages/05334956.pdf

On page 7 (9th page of the PDF) there's a tabulated spec for t<sub>V</sub>, "Horizontal lines per field" (Min: 256, Typ: 262, Max: 268) puzzlingly given in units t<sub>H</sub>, which is the horizontal start pulse signal period - I can only assume this means that there are 256 to 268 lines per field, and that given each scan line has a duration t<sub>H</sub>, t<sub>V</sub> is the duration to complete all horizontal lines in the field. My real question is on the referenced note:

> Note 2: Please don't use odd horizontal lines to drive LCD panel for both odd and even fields simultaneously.

What ever could *that* mean I wonder. Is it a warning that I can only use an odd number of lines every other frame? Is it some sort of caution against interlacing frames?

Comment: That panel is built for component video compatibility, so it has some measures to support interlace mode. I think *simultaneously* is a wrong translation from Chinese, because you cannot have both fields at the same time ("simultaneously"). I bet it should mean: *When you don't do interlace, double the even field, not the odd field*.

Comment: Can you explain *When you don't do interlace, double the even field, not the odd field.* more?

Comment: For interlace mode, you send the even frame with lines 0,2,4,... then the odd frame with lines 1,3,5,... A CRT can display both, using the afterglow of the screen and with a half-line vertical shift between them. A LCD can't do this so the driver has to simulate that "afterglow" somehow. That means, when you don't do interlace, you have to send two *identical* fields to avoid smearing between frames where the contents changes. This halves your frame rate to 30Hz. In addition, you should use the even frame ("even lines") for this. This is only important when your source is a video source,

Comment: because editing happens before even frames. When you use the odd frame ("odd lines") instead, you do not double a frame at cuts but use one frame from the pre-cut section and one from the post-cut section, which results in smearing and flashes again.

Comment: Put it in an answer and get your +15 rep. I don't think I'll find a more authoritative answer, and this seems like a very plausible explanation.

Comment: Let's wait for a better answer. As written, what that note is supposed to mean is just a guess. Do you by chance have the original chinese datasheet?

Comment: I do not, but we could try to find it. If you Google this phrase, you'll also find a lot of other datasheets with this same text.